# $('.col-md-9').width() returns 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented Navigation Tabs using Bootstrap. I am trying to get the width of a div when one particular tab becomes active. While the active tab is detected correctly, the width is returned 0. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pThn6/811/

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#aaa" data-toggle="tab">AAA</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#bbb" data-toggle="tab">BBB</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ccc" data-toggle="tab">CCC</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="tabs">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="aaa">
        <div class='col-md-9'>
            ...Content vol...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="bbb">

    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="ccc">...Content...</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function(e) {
        var s = "" + (e.target);

        if(s.search('aaa') != -1) {
            alert($('.col-md-9').css("width"));
        }
    });
})
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Looks like you're getting the width before it is made active. i get -30 on first click, and 530 on second.

Comment: alerts `75` for me - windows/FF

Comment: That example on jsfiddle is working.

Comment: It alerts a 0 for me on my Windows / Chrome

Comment: @Jamiec It is returning percentage width and not the value in pixels. Hence 75....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

timing issue, the tab hasn't opened yet so it hasn't resized the column, try this

http://jsfiddle.net/pThn6/812/

```
setTimeout(function() {
    alert($('.col-md-9').width());
}, 100);
```

a better solution would be to hook into the open event provided by bootstrap, something like this

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var tab = "" + (e.target);

    if(tab.search('aaa') != -1) {
        alert($('.col-md-9').width());
    }
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pThn6/819/

Comment: This works correctly. But it is returning the value in percent: 75. Is there a way I can change that?

Comment: I guess I figured why that is happening. Thanks for your help!