# jquery: Change text color to match navbar background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've set up a menu to load various stylesheets (which I don't want to edit). What I want to do is set the color of a css class to be the same as the color of navbar-inverse's background-color.

Here's my code so far;

```
var themes = {
  "default": "css/default.bootstrap.min.css",
  "theme1": "css/theme1.bootstrap.min.css",
  "theme2": "css/theme2.bootstrap.min.css",
  "app": "css/app.css"
};


$(function () {
  var themesheet = $('<link href="' + themes['default'] + '" rel="stylesheet" />');
  themesheet.appendTo('head');
  var theColorIs = $('.navbar-inverse').css("background-color");
  $('.text-primary2').css('color', theColorIs);

  $('.theme-link').click(function () {
      var themeurl = themes[$(this).attr('data-theme')];
      themesheet.attr('href', themeurl);
      var apptheme = $('<link href="' + themes['app'] + '" rel="stylesheet" />');
      apptheme.appendTo('head');
      var theColorIs = $('.navbar-inverse').css("background-color");
      $('.text-primary2').css('color', theColorIs);
  });
});
```

Basically, it loads some bootswatch samples, then reloads my own app.css to override a bunch of things. Then I store the BG color of navbar-inverse to a variable and attempt to set .text-primary2's color to match.

It kind of works but it only changes to the color of the previously selected theme, so if I choose the same one twice then I will eventually catch up.

I can make changes to my app.css, html, or javascript but I'm trying to avoid making changes to individual themes.

I should add that I'm a total novice with regards to jquery, javascript and web development in general.

Comment: This is happening because you are trying to access it while it is still loading. Hence, it tries to access the already stored value which is that of the previous page. Use timeout function instead. Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461511/col-md-9-width-returns-0

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect.